# How to handle parameter in POST request in expressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on my first project in my company and stuck at post request using expressjs.

Below is my code for post request

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const request = require('request')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/cruamsApi/updateUsers', (req, res) => {
    
    const DisplayName = req.body.DisplayName
    const EmployeeNumber = req.body.EmployeeNumber
    const RegDate = req.body.RegDate
    const url = 'http://localhost:8009/CruAmsAPI/Employee'
    
    request (
        {
            url: url,
            json: true,
            body: {
                "EmployeeNumber": EmployeeNumber,
                "DisplayName": DisplayName,
                "RegDate": RegDate
            }
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
            
            if(!error) {
                res.send(response)
            } else {
                res.send(error)
            }
        }
    )
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('server is listening port ' + PORT)
})
```

When I make a POST request, it is keep returning "EmployeeNumber parameter is required" error message from an API. I tried to double quote the keys "EmployeeNumber" but still having a same issue. Included headers too but didn't really work. POST request does work in POSTMAN.

Comment: Are you trying to send or handle a POST request? `const request = require('request')` is unrelated to ExpressJS. Can you start the server in a debugger and add a breakpoint at `const EmployeeNumber = req.body.EmployeeNumber`? What's the value of `EmployeeNumber` after this line?

Comment: @ThomasSablik How can I start the server in a debugger? Sorry I've never tried a debugger before.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I just googled and working on it now : )

Comment: @ThomasSablik Nothing happens at a debugger breakpoint

Comment: Using a debugger you can see the values of each variable in each step. What's the value of `EmployeeNumber` after the line `const EmployeeNumber = req.body.EmployeeNumber`?

Comment: It's weird. I added a debugger line above "const EmployeeNumber = req.body.EmployeeNumber" and ran "node inspect server.js". It breaks on start in server.js:1 and when I type cont and hit enter it doesn't breaks at the debugger line and instead it passes it and reach to the bottom of the code.

Comment: Are you trying to send a POST request or are you trying to listen on a port and send a POST request after a POST request was received? Where is `app.listen` in your code snippet? The function in `app.post` is a a callback function only called after a POST request was received.

Comment: So I make a post request to url '/cruamsApi/updateUsers' from frontend and in my backend it will make another post request to an external url which is 'http://localhost:8009/CruAmsAPI/Employee' with the body. It is working when I use postman so the API is good but it is keep giving me   "Message: 'Parameter Error. EmployeeNumber parameter is required."

Comment: It's impossible to help without more information. You could log the request and post it

Comment: {"Id":0,"UserState":0,"Status":200,"Message":"Parameter Error. EmployeeNumber parameter is required."}

Comment: This is actual message I'm getting from an API. status is 200 so it is connected but the EmployeeNumber...

Comment: I stringify the body part ```const formData = JSON.stringify(form)``` and attached it as a body and still a same issue

Comment: I asked for the request, not the response.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I added method: 'POST' in my request and it resolved the issue but thanks a lot for your comments

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to send the EmployeeNumber in your request?
If it works in Postman, it should work. I think that your issue is in your front-end which doesn't send any EmplyeeNumber in the request.